# Separate hours from minutes in array of times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently working on a project with Redux and React.
To fill in an input I have to request the server and the server returns an array of times(it may have one member or several).
like this:

```
{
  "start_hour": [
    "10:00",
    "15:55",
    "20:08"
  ]
}
```

I have to separate the hours and minutes and have two **states**.
like this:

```
{
  "hours": [
    "10",
    "15",
    "20"
  ];
  "minutes": [
    "00",
    "55",
    "08"
  ];
}
```

How can I do this? Are there any libraries for this?

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) plus [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce` and `String.split` function, this can be done as follows.

```js
const input = {
  "start_hour": [
    "10:00",
    "15:55",
    "20:08"
  ]
};

const output = input.start_hour.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const curArr = cur.split(':');
  acc.hours.push(curArr[0]);
  acc.minutes.push(curArr[1]);
  return acc;
}, { hours: [], minutes: [] });
console.log(output);
```